# Ошибка Undefined index: page

Tags: php

В файле шаблона имеется код

```
/*Add a Theme Options Page*/
function mytheme_add_admin() {

    global $themename, $shortname, $options;

    if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {

        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

                foreach ($options as $value) {
                    update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); }

                foreach ($options as $value) {
                    if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); } else { delete_option( $value['id'] ); } }

                header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&saved=true");
                die;

        } else if( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

            foreach ($options as $value) {
                delete_option( $value['id'] ); }

            header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&reset=true");
            die;

        }
    }

    add_theme_page($themename." Options", "".$themename." Options", 'edit_themes', basename(__FILE__), 'mytheme_admin');

}
```

строка `if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {` выдаёт ошибку Undefined index: page

В поисках решения, нашёл эту ветку https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468275/undefined-index-page-in но, ошибка исчезает, а тема меняется на дефолтную и я её не могу включить. В итоге откатился назад к этой ошибке.

Любой ваш совет будет принят во внимание.

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно `if (isset( $_GET['page']) &&  $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. И ошибка исчезла и тема не слетает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `url` нет такого `GET` параметра как page. Т.е `mysite.com?page=page`

Вам нужно предусмотреть логику работы скрипта в таком случае. К примеру Вместо

```
if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {
  //code
}
```

К примеру

```
$page = $_GET['page'] ?? null;
if ($page == basename(__FILE__) ) {
  //code
}
```

Либо

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {
  //code
}
```